# Cube inscribed in a hemi-spherical shape

Tags: geometry

What should be the approach to determine the distance? It seems that we need to form a Pythagorean triangle for this one. If it was a cube inside a sphere we could have easily said that the diameter of the sphere will be equal to the diagonal of the cube. But I am not able to visualize this problem.

[image]

Comment: Welcome the Mathematics Stack Exchange. A quick tour of the site (https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most of your time here. For typesetting your equations, please use MathJax:
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: Let $O$ be the common center of the base and the hemisphere and $C$ be the vertex of cube above $B$. What is the relationship between $|AB|$ and $|OC|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance from a corner at the base to the center of the top is the same as the distance from the center of the base to a corner at the top. This length is the radius of the hemisphere: $10$m

Answer (score 0):

Let $O$ be a center of our sphere and $K$ be a top left vertex of the cuboid.

Now, easy to see that $OKAB$ is a parallelogram ($AK||OB$ and $AK=OB$), which gives $$AB=OK=\frac{20}{2}=10.$$